# Reference a class name as a variable

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

I'm wondering if there is a better way to write this block of code.  It's extremely redundant and before i did it this way i was thinking there should be a way to do it with variables as the class names but ran into many issues and eventually ended up doing it this way.  Now every time i look at it it bothers me.  I did quite a bit of research on this topic and did not come up with anything. Possibly because i'm not sure what doing something like this would be called.

For sake of argument, assume the following code is in a function that is called when a SKSpriteNode is tapped.  Each "button" is named for the scene that it will be transitioning to.  There are actually 12 more of these `case` statements.

```
let name = sender.name
switch(name){
    case "newGame":
        defaults.set(true,forKey: "isFirstRun")
        defaults.set(true,forKey: "isNewGame")
        let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
        let nextScene = Setup(fileNamed:"Setup")
        nextScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
        break
    case "IceFishing":
        defaults.set(2, forKey: "currentLocation")
        let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
        let nextScene = IceFishing(fileNamed:"IceFishing")
        nextScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
        break
    case "OpeningScene":
        let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
        let nextScene = OpeningScene(fileNamed:"OpeningScene")
        nextScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
        break
    case "House":
        let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
        let nextScene = SodHouse(fileNamed:"House")
        nextScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
        break
    default:
        break
}
```

I would think (or hope) there is a way to do something like...

```
let name = sender.name
let _Class = name as! SKScene //Not right, but i was guessing

let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
let nextScene = _Class(fileNamed:name)
nextScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
```

All of the sks files and Swift classes are named the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You do not need to do something like  `SodHouse(fileNamed:"House")`,  `SKScene(fileNamed:"House")` will do what you want as long as your sks file has the custom class set to the correct class name

Comment: @Knight0fDragon if what you just said is accurate, then I'll be able to do exactly what I want to do.  But if it is, then what is the purpose of doing it the way I have here? I was under the impression it must be done this way.

Comment: No, that way is the old way (iOS 9 and before),  If there is a special function unique to the class that you need, then you would just cast.  `if let scene = scene as? SodHouse`

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to have the code look like this (I added some guards for you):

```
let name = sender.name
let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
guard let nextScene = SKScene(fileNamed:sender.name) else {fatalError("unable to find next scene")}
guard let scene = scene else {fatalError("unable to find scene")}
guard let view = scene.view else {fatalError("unable to find view")}

nextScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

case "newGame":
    //I would avoid using defaults unless you plan on saving when the app exits
    defaults.set(true,forKey: "isFirstRun")
    defaults.set(true,forKey: "isNewGame")

case "IceFishing":
    defaults.set(2, forKey: "currentLocation")

default: break
}

view.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
```

Basically what we are doing is relying on the custom class field in the sks file to load the custom class for us.

Edit:  Now to clean up the code even more,  I would ditch using defaults.  You should only have to use this when you want to save data across gaming sessions, not across plays.

```
let name = sender.name
let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
guard let nextScene = SKScene(fileNamed:sender.name) else {fatalError("unable to find next scene")}
guard let scene = scene else {fatalError("unable to find scene")}
guard let view = scene.view else {fatalError("unable to find view")}

nextScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

nextScene.userData += scene.userData
//Move these to the SKS file under UserData section, then you can pull it using scene.userData?
//    defaults.set(2, forKey: "currentLocation")    
//    defaults.set(true,forKey: "isFirstRun") 
//    defaults.set(true,forKey: "isNewGame")

view.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
```

Comment: Well this definitely makes sense now.  I just was told (or assumed) I should reference the class name directly.  But I suppose the purpose of doing that is only for when you have one SKS file and multiple classes that might use it.  But with my way of each SKS file has its own custom class; this makes perfect sense.  The lightbulb has gone off! Lol thanks!

Comment: It is silly to have 1 SKS file with multiple classes,  there are better solutions like using components

Comment: All of those UserDefaults _are_ used across game sessions.  I'm familiar with UserData and use that in other places.

Comment: your numbers are constant though, not seeing why that has to get stored at a later data

Comment: So there is no reason anymore to use `OpeningScene(fileNamed:"OpeningScene")`? That's just old syntax?  I guess I'm just struggling with why that is even an option.

Comment: no, it still has a purpose, just not for what you need